# How to control social share image and text when sharing shiny apps on social media (deployed with shinyapps.io)

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

When I share my shinyapp on social media, code is displayed under the header image which doesn't look very good. How do I control the social share image and text for my shinyapp? I've deployed the app using shinyapps.io.

See image below as example:

[image]

Link to app: https://regionalinnovationdatalab.shinyapps.io/Dashboard/

Link to Gitlab where App code and data can be found: https://gitlab.com/r.chappell/2019_ElectionApp_RIDL

Code from UI where header image is inserted:

```
     ui <- shiny::fluidPage( #use fluid page so that the app adjusts to the user's screen size and device

    titlePanel(div(img(src='DATA DASHBOARD V3.png', height = 80))), #header title with image as the whole header ( must save header image in a subfolder titled 'www')
  tags$head(tags$style(
    type="text/css",
        "img {max-width: 100%; width: 100%; height: auto}" #makes image size responsive to device and screen
    )),
    theme = "journal", #selected theme from shinythemes package
   title=" RIDL: 2019 Election App", #title of web brower tab
    br(),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeking help from R studio support, they said there was an issue with java script code when published to shinyapps.io which is why it didn't work.

I ended up finding a work around.

I changed this code:

```
 ui <- shiny::fluidPage( #use fluid page so that the app adjusts to the user's screen size and device

    titlePanel(div(img(src='DATA DASHBOARD V3.png', height = 80))), #header title with image as the whole header ( must save header image in a subfolder titled 'www')
  tags$head(tags$style(
    type="text/css",
        "img {max-width: 100%; width: 100%; height: auto}" #makes image size responsive to device and screen
    )),
```

To this:

```
  ui<-shiny::fluidPage(
    titlePanel(div(img(src='DATA_DASHBOARD_V3.png', height = "auto", width = "100%")))),
```

This code removes the java script code that was appearing before but it doesn't include a thumbnail image when shared to facebook. R Studio said that they were working on this issue but this is a solution for the mean time.

[image]

Comment: What if I want the thumbnail image when shared to facebook? I try, but can not achieve that