# Preview image on Facebook is not showing when deploying apps on shiyapps.io

Tags: r, facebook, shiny, shinyapps

I have created shiny app and published it on shinyapp.io, now I would like to share it on Facebook. When I try to share it preview photo on social media are not loaded.

[image]

I have tried to apply answers from:

- https://github.com/gadenbuie/metathis/issues/9
- [How to control social share image and text when sharing shiny apps on social media (deployed with shinyapps.io)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55348816/how-to-control-social-share-image-and-text-when-sharing-shiny-apps-on-social-med)
- https://pkg.garrickadenbuie.com/metathis/index.html

but they do not work for me.

That is my ui beginning looked like:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  title = "We Wrocławiu brakuje bezpiecznych i łatwo dostępnych miejsc do parkowania rowerów",
  titlePanel(
    title = "We Wrocławiu brakuje bezpiecznych i łatwo dostępnych miejsc do parkowania rowerów",
    div(
      img(
        src = 'PREVIEW.png', 
        height = 80
        )
      ),
    ), #header title with image as the whole header ( must save header image in a subfolder titled 'www')
```

and

```
    ui <- fluidPage(
      title = "We Wrocławiu brakuje bezpiecznych i łatwo dostępnych miejsc do parkowania rowerów",
  meta() %>%
    meta_social(
      title = "We Wrocławiu brakuje bezpiecznych i łatwo dostępnych miejsc do parkowania rowerów",
      description = "<meta> and social media cards for web things in R",
      url = "https://wrodata.shinyapps.io/v3__kopia/",
      image = "https://imgur.com/a/0YNcTQ9",
      image_alt = "https://wrodata.shinyapps.io/v3__kopia/"
    ),
```

and

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  title = "We Wrocławiu brakuje bezpiecznych i łatwo dostępnych miejsc do parkowania rowerów",
   tags$head(
     # Facebook OpenGraph tags - image to share when social sharing app
     tags$meta(property = "og:title", content = share$title),
     tags$meta(property = "og:type", content = "website"),
     tags$meta(property = "og:url", content = "https://imgur.com/a/0YNcTQ9"),
     # tags$meta(property = "og:url", content = share$url),
     # tags$meta(property = "og:image", content = share$image),
     tags$meta(property = "og:image", content = "https://imgur.com/a/0YNcTQ9"),
     tags$meta(property = "og:image:width", content = "300"),
     tags$meta(property = "og:image:height", content = "400"),
     tags$meta(property = "og:description", content = share$description)
     ),
```

all without any changes

Link to app: https://wrodata.shinyapps.io/v3__kopia/

**Full code**: https://github.com/WroData/Olbin_mapa_rowery_i_auta

Comment: `https://imgur.com/a/0YNcTQ9` is not the URL of an image, but of an HTML document.

Comment: And even if you were to figure out the actual image URL on imgur's CDN, they probably have some sort of hotlinking protection in place, that will collide with the scraper trying to request them. You should really host those images yourself, rather than trying to use a free image hosting service.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, it is not link to photo. Changed that, but as you predicted it did not help :(